# R- Using grepl search for a pattern and generate multiple binary variables

Tags: r, string, grepl

Brand new to R and stack.  Hope I'm asking this question correctly.

I have numerous string variables that I need to recode into unique columns.  The data are collected from a survey.  For example, if a respondent selected "2-black" and "22-hispanic" the data are recorded in variable "string" as "2;22."

I need to recode the variables into unique binary variables with colnames as: "Black", "White", "Hispanic", etc.  The columns should be populated as "TRUE" or "FALSE" by searching for number patterns in the string value.

I tried writing a function using "grepl" but it's no good.  First I had to create an object "string" from the data frame (code not included). Then I ran into problems distinguishing between, say, "2" and "22".

If you run the code below you can see it's not working as intended

```
    strg_to_many<-function(newcol, string, number) {
    for (i in 1:length(number)){
    string<-newcol[I]
    df_temp[string]<-grepl(number[i], df_temp$string)
      }
    return(df_temp)
     }

    df_temp<-data.frame(string=c("22;2", "20", "40,20", "2"))
    newcol<-c("black" , "white", "hispanic", "other")
    number<-c("2", "20", "22", "40")
    string<-c("22;2", "20", "40;20", "2")

    df <- strg_to_many(newcol, string, number)
```

The output I expect is:

- string    black  white  hispanic other
- 22;2       TRUE   FALSE   TRUE   FALSE
- 20         FALSE  TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
- 40;20      FALSE  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
- 2          TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you expect to happen to `40,20`? Will that be `Other == TRUE` & `white == TRUE`? In the case of two numbers, how are they separated? In your example you seem to have both a semicolon and a comma. It would help if you were to provide the full expected output for the sample data you give (not just one row).

Comment: My mistake, sorry.  They should be separated by a ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your expected output, but perhaps the following is what you're after.

The idea is to store the mapping between `number` and `newcol` in a `data.frame` and then perform a `left_join` after separating entries from `string`.

*Note that this assumes that the first number in `string` is the number that pertains to `newcol`.*

```
df_map <- data.frame(
    number = number,
    newcol = newcol)

library(tidyverse)
df_temp %>%
    separate(string, c("x1", "x2"), remove = FALSE, fill = "right") %>%
    left_join(df_map, by = c("x1" = "number")) %>%
    mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
    spread(newcol, val, fill = FALSE) %>%
    select(-x1, -x2)
#  string black hispanic other white
#1      2  TRUE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2     20 FALSE    FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#3   22;2 FALSE     TRUE FALSE FALSE
#4  40,20 FALSE    FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

### Update

In response to your clarifications, the following seems to reproduce your expected output

```
df_temp %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    mutate(tmp = str_split(string, "[;,]")) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    left_join(df_map, by = c("tmp" = "number")) %>%
    mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
    select(-tmp) %>%
    spread(newcol, val, fill = FALSE) %>%
    select(-row)
#  string black hispanic other white
#1   22;2  TRUE     TRUE FALSE FALSE
#2     20 FALSE    FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#3  40,20 FALSE    FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#4      2  TRUE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Maurits!   I feel like this is much, much closer. I do need to evaluate all of the information in string.  So for rows 3 I also want "black" to be "TRUE" because  "2" is endorsed.   And in row 4 I want "Other" to be "TRUE" because "20" is endorsed.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't see your initial question.  They should be separated by a ";"

Comment: Hi @KateMcDonald. I've made an edit; is this what you're after (still not quite sure what you mean by "endorsed" in this context).

Comment: No worries @KateMcDonald; glad it was helpful.